# Unexpected exception while validating invocable action requests

Tags: validation, salesforce

When we try to change the pricebook to add products in opportunity; we are not able to do it because of one validation rule(that is we can not edit opportunity if this opportunity does not contain opportunity products  )

I wrote the validation rule:

NOT(OR(ISNEW(),IF(ISCHANGED(Pricebook2Id),true,HasOpportunityLineItem) ))

when the validation rule should trigger, it triggers and showing error message as expected, but when it should not trigger it is showing some different error( not validation rule error) like:

"Can't update Price Book. Unexpected exception while validating invocable action requests"

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Those opportunities have no added product yet, right? I guess you have added the rule later because with a rule like that you shouldn't be able to save an opportunity without a product.

Answer (score 0):

jhumur

I think the appropriate object should be PricebookEntry rather than Pricebook2.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).